# How to color border when error is displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

1Departing & Arriving

```
            <fielset class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="FDestination" >From</label>
                <select name="Location" id = "Location" onchange="checkforblank()"  >
                     <option value = "Please Select" >Please Select </option>
                    <option value="Newport">Newport</option>
                    <option value="Mahdi">London</option>
                    <option value="Cardiff">Cardiff</option>
                    <option value="Cilo">Brazil </option>
                </select>



            <fielset class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="FDestination">To</label>
                <select name="LocationTo" id = "LocationTo" onchange="checkforblank()">
                    <option value = "Please Select">Please Select </option>
                    <option value="Cardiff">Cardiff</option>
                    <option value="Mahdi">London</option>
                    <option value="Newport">Newport</option>
                    <option value="Cilo">Brazil</option>
                </select>
```

```
<script>

  function checkforblank() {

    var location = document.getElementById('Location');
    var invalidFrom = location.value == "Please Select";
    var locationTo = document.getElementById('LocationTo');
    var InvalidTo = locationTo.value == "Please Select";

    if (invalidFrom || InvalidTo) {
        alert('Please enter first name');
        location.className = 'error';
        InvalidTo.className = 'error'; 
    }
    else {
        location.className = '';
    }

    return !invalid;
}


</script>


.error {
    border: solid 5px #FF0
}
```

I want borders for the selected option to be coloured when user chooses wrong option ("Please Choose") in either box. What happens now is that when I click submit it displays alert then for a few seconds the colour comes up in one box and the other box is blank, then it just disappears.

When user chooses the "Please Choose " option in either box I want the error to be displayed in that box e.g. if both boxes have "Please Choose" then both highlighted or if one box has "Please Choose" and the other box is valid then only the one box with wrong option is highlighted. Also that when OK is clicked in the alert box the boxes remain highlighted until changed to a valid option.

Comment: Make a change event, check if both of the id inputs have a value of "please select", if yes then use jquery css function and do the coloring with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would do is fix the `fielset` to be `fieldset` as it should be.

Second, I would add the closing tags for them, like so;

```
<fieldset class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="Location">From</label>
    <select name="Location" id="Location" onchange="checkforblank()">
        <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
        <option value="Newport">Newport</option>
        <option value="Mahdi">London</option>
        <option value="Cardiff">Cardiff</option>
        <option value="Cilo">Brazil</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="LocationTo">To</label>
    <select name="LocationTo" id="LocationTo" onchange="checkforblank()">
        <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
        <option value="Cardiff">Cardiff</option>
        <option value="Mahdi">London</option>
        <option value="Newport">Newport</option>
        <option value="Cilo">Brazil</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

After that, you didn't specify whether using jQuery was an option, so this answer is dependent on that answer, since it uses jQuery.

```
$('#Location, #LocationTo').change(function(e) {
    var fromVal   = $('#Location').val(),
        toVal     = $('#LocationTo').val(),
        borderCol = '';

    if (fromVal == "Please Select" || toVal == "Please Select") {
        borderCol = 'red';
    } else {
        borderCol = 'black';
    }

    $('select[id="Location"],select[id="LocationTo"]').parent().css({
        'border-color' : borderCol
    });
});
```

Link to the fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/MrMarlow/eg8k4vL7/
```

If using jQuery is an option, include it like so

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit** :: Fixed label `to` attributes to point to the corresponding id.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If I wanted to change the code into JQuery how would I run it in html i.e. how can i call the function on submit so it can run?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JavaScript/JQuery code that solves your problem (whenever both destination match, the border becomes red because you can not travel from point A to point A, it doesn't make any sense).

**Code:**

```
var index_one;
var index_two;

    $('#Location, #LocationTo').change(function (e) {

        index_one = $("#Location")[0].selectedIndex;
        index_two = $("#LocationTo")[0].selectedIndex;
    });
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        if ($("#Location>option").eq(index_one).text() == $("#LocationTo>option").eq(index_two).text()) {
            $('#Location, #LocationTo').css("border-color", "red");
        } else {
            $('#Location, #LocationTo').css("border-color", "black");
        }
    });
```

**Fiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/eg8k4vL7/1/

Also if you want to handle the possibility of a input that has not been given a value you can add this two extra if's

```
else if($("#Location>option").eq(index_one).text() =="Please Select")
    {
        alert ("Select an option");
    }
      else if($("#LocationTo>option").eq(index_one).text() =="Please Select")
    {
        alert ("Select an option");
    }
```

Instead of .text() you can use .val() function which is more appropriate in this situation.

To call the above code put it in between the  tags

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> //jquery lib, must include
<script>
//the above code
<script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thankyou , how can I implement this into my JS to get it running? would I need any plugins?